# Are there any examples of viruses that have powered motion or do they all rely on passive diffusion?

Tags: virus, virology

Swimming, or any locomotion will presumably require energy which will in turn require metabolism which viruses lack supposedly.

Are they general able to direct their movement in any manner (e.g like sailing) or are they strictly limited to Brownian-like motion? If not, are there any exceptional examples that indeed can control their motion?

Comment: Click bait title ("can viruses swim") won't attract the people that know an answer IMO (feel free to roll back). I came here to close the question, but it's actually a reasonable and interesting question! Unfortunately, there is already a well answered duplicate.